# How to print R variables in middle of String

Tags: r

I am trying to print out a line that contains a mixture of a String and a variable. Here is the R code at present:

```
cat("<set name=\",df$timeStamp,\" value=\",df$Price,\" ></set>\n")
```

Here is what it prints out when run:

```
<set name=",df$timeStamp," value=",df$Price," ></set>
```

I would like it to have the value of df$timeStamp and df$Price printed out. I would like for example the following:

```
<set name="2010-08-18 12:00:59" value="17.56" ></set>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong in the code?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Anthony.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that R does not evaluate *any* expression withing the quotes - it is just printing the string you defined. There are multiple ways around it. For example, you can use the `sprintf` function (untested because you do not provide a reproducible example):

```
   cat(sprintf("<set name=\"%s\" value=\"%f\" ></set>\n", df$timeStamp, df$Price))
```

Comment: When using single quotes, this makes the whole thing easier to read...   
`cat(sprintf('<set name="%s" value="%f" ></set>\n', df$timeStamp, df$Price))`

Answer (score 16):

You're missing some extra quotes.  Try this:

```
cat('<set name=\"',df$timeStamp,'\" value=\"',df$Price,'\" ></set>\n')
```

Here's a working example of what I mean:

```
cat("a b c -> \"", letters[1:3], "\"\n")
```

Comment: If you want to be super-slick, you can avoid having to escape quotes (in this case) by using single-quotes to delineate the string and double-quotes within it: `cat('a b c -> "', letters[1:3], '"\n')`

Answer (score 9):

There is now a very convenient function to perform string formatting that works pretty much like Python `f-strings`. `str_glue` is part of the [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_glue.html) package.

```
library(stringr)

str_glue('<set name="{df$timeStamp}" value="{df$Price}"></set>')

# <set name="2010-08-18 12:00:59" value="17.56"></set>
```

Answer (score 3):

Cat works just fine without extra libraries and escapes:

```
cat('<set name="', df$timeStamp, '" value="', df$Price, '"></set>\n', sep='')
```

output:

```
<set name="2010-08-18 12:00:59" value="17.56"></set>
```

Comment: This is nearly identical to Shane's answer.  The addition of the `sep` argument should probably be a comment on his answer rather than a new post.