# Format print statement

Tags: r

I would like to format output of a print statement so that elements in the print statement 
are separated by a small uniform gap, a gap of either 1, 3 or 5 empty spaces.  Is that
possible?

In the example below, I think all of the elements in the print statement are assumed to be 
as long as the first element in the print statement (here either as long as `aa1` or `aa2`).

The `print.gap` statement does not result in the desired format.  It simply adds an 
additional constant number of spaces between each element.

```
aa1 <- 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
aa2 <- 'abc'

bb  <- 10
cc  <- 222

print(c(aa1,bb,cc))

# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10"                         "222" 

print(c(aa2,bb,cc))

# [1] "abc" "10"  "222"

# desired output:

# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   "10"   "222" 
#
# or
#
# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   10   222
```

Thank you for any advice.  Perhaps I must use a `cat` statement and `sprintf` instead of a `print` statement.  Maybe some variation of this: [How to print R variables in middle of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516008/how-to-print-r-variables-in-middle-of-string)

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for--you want a fixed separation of 1, 3 or 5 spaces, the same every time, or varying? Otherwise `sprintf()` or `paste(aa1,bb,cc,sep="   ")` might be what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you partway there:

```
x <- c(aa1,bb,cc)

options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
cat(paste(dQuote(x), collapse="   "), "\n")
# "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   "10"   "222"
```

I say "partway" because the code above doesn't take care of line-wrapping: if you hand it a very long vector of characters strings, they will all be cat'd to a single very long non-wrapping line...

---

**Edited to show one method of wrapping the lines:**

You can get line-wrapping by using a combination of `strwrap()` (thanks @mnel) and `gsub()`, :

```
xs <- c(x,x,x,x)

cat(gsub("\" \"", "\"   \"", 
    strwrap(paste(dQuote(xs), collapse=" "), 70)), sep="\n")
# "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   "10"   "222"   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
# "10"   "222"   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   "10"   "222"
# "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   "10"   "222"
```

(The call to `gsub()` is needed if more than one space is needed between the vector elements, because `strwrap()` destroys whitespace in the input.)

Comment: Use `strwrap` to wrap at some sensible length (such as `options()$width`) eg `cat(strwrap(paste(rep(dQuote(x),10), collapse="   "), 80), "\n")`

Comment: @mnel.  Nice. Unfortunately, `cat(strwrap(paste(rep(dQuote(x),10), collapse=" "), 80), sep="\n")` appears to only leave one space between elements, no matter how many you specify in the `collapse=` argument... Any idea of a way around that?

Comment: I was just trying to write it up as an answer and finding the same issue. Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my comment as an answer

you can create your own `print.character` method and use `strwrap` to wrap to sensible line length.

Unfortunately `strwrap` destroys all whitespace and replaces it with a single space

```
print.character <- function(x, width = getOption('width'), .sep = '  '){
  cat(paste(strwrap(paste(dQuote(x), collapse = .sep, sep =.sep), width),  
  collapse = '\n'), '\n')
}
x <- c(aa1,bb,cc)
print(x)
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
print(rep(x,10))
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
## "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "10" "222"
```

It will not work as expected with whitespace within the character variables

```
print('Does not work  with strings with  variable spaces that you \n might \t \t \t want to keep')
"Does not quite work with strings with variable spaces that you might want to keep"
```

Comment: Here it is. I think this belongs with your answer rather than mine, since `strwrap()` was your idea, so feel free to edit yours to add it if you think it works well enough: `cat(gsub(" ", "   ", strwrap(paste(rep(dQuote(x),10), collapse=" "), 70)), sep="\n")`.