# How to make column names/ dataframe names a string with a variable in it (R)

Tags: r

```
this.year<-2014 
x<-this.year-1 
y<-this.year-2
x.s<-x-2000 
y.s<-y-2000
tpop_y.s<-acs.fetch(endyear=x,span=1,geography=mystates,variable="B01003_001", col.names="DM_TPOP_x.s")  
tpop_x.s<-acs.fetch(endyear=y,span=1,geography=mystates,variable="B01003_001",col.names="DM_TPOP_y.s")
```

I'm using the package `acs` to pull out data from the American community survey to update an infographics website. I hope to run the code every year by inputing the current year in `this.year` and having the code update data for the past 2 years, `x` and `y`.

If `this.year` is 2015, `x` is 2014, `x.s` is 14, `y` is 2013, `y.s` is 13. The end result I want is (for y) the data frame name `tpop_13` with the column name `DM_TPOP_13`. (for x) the data frame name `tpop_14` with the column name `DM_TPOP_14`.

The code is pulling the desired data correctly, but this code returns (for y) the data frame name `tpop_y.s` with the column name `DM_TPOP_y.s`. (for x) the data frame name `tpop_x.s` with the column name `DM_TPOP_x.s`.
I tried searching for similar questions and found this one: [How to print R variables in middle of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516008/how-to-print-r-variables-in-middle-of-string)

I tried applying the answer by using the quotes `\"',x.s,'\"` to solve my problem, but it doesn't work. The code returns (for x) the column name `DM_TPOP_...x.s...`. I understand that R does not evaluate any expression within the quotes - it just prints the string you defined. But how can you get around this problem so that there can be a variable in a string?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need such a complicated example? I've never seen `acs.fetch` before and doubt that it is important to a question of strings and variable names...

Comment: `acs.fetch` is found in the package `acs` that is not a commonly used package. I'm sorry if the example seems complicated. It is just how the arguments in acs.fetch works.

Comment: The `assign` function may help, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r

Comment: I have posted an answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can work: store the data in the list `kk`, so that first element ,`kk[[1]]` or `kk[["tpop_13"]]`, gives the data for 2013 and second element,`kk[[2]]` or `kk[["tpop_12"]]` gives the data for 2012, with the name of each element as you suggested.

```
wa=geo.make(state="WA")
kk<-lapply(c(x,y),function(i){
  acs.fetch(endyear=i,span=1,geography=wa,variable="B01003_001", col.names=paste0("DM_TPOP_",i-2000)) 
   })


names(kk)<-paste0("tpop_",c(x-2000,y-2000))
   kk 
        $tpop_13
    ACS DATA: 
     2013 ;
      Estimates w/90% confidence intervals;
      for different intervals, see confint()
               DM_TPOP_13   
    Washington 6971406 +/- 0

    $tpop_12
    ACS DATA: 
     2012 ;
      Estimates w/90% confidence intervals;
      for different intervals, see confint()
               DM_TPOP_12   
    Washington 6897012 +/- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like `paste`, `paste0`, and `sprintf` to construct strings from string constants and variables.  There is also functionality in the gsubfn package to do Perl like string interpolation.